# How to activate callByValue for MBean Calls (JBoss)

Tags: jboss, jmx

I have the following problem:

Two wars are deployed to a tomcat 5.1 Application Server.

War1 registeres some MBeans that will return Objects of types defined in War1

War2 tries to access the MBean but Gets a ClassCastException when getting trying to cast the Object retrieved to The Object expected. The class of the Object is provided in a Jar to the war2.

I found out that the Object passed to war2 was loaded by the classLoader of the war1. In order to solve the problem I would like to call the MBean Method by value and not by reference as it appears to be now.

Can anyone tell me how to change that in JBoss?

Answer (score 0):

Put the common data classes from that MBeans in a jar that you put either
- in a ear file containing both .war files (if they should go in an ear)
- server/lib/ if you only have wars and no ear

In both cases, you should remove those classes from the war files, so that classloader delegation will find them in "broader scope"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Putting the lib in the server/lib dir is unfortunately not an option for me (company stuff). I might think of creating an EAR with both wars in them. I assume there is no way to tell Jboss that it should not call the mbeans directly? In JBoss4 the MBean was called remotely.